# Update SQL Server stored procedure - switch columns in the parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a basic stored procedure as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdate1]
    @registration_id NCHAR(8),
    @registration_status INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Test1
    SET Registration_Status = @registration_status
    WHERE Registration_id = @registration_id;
END
```

This stored procedure works without issue, however the `registration_id` isn't the parameter I would like to pass in.

I have a three columns in my table:

```
Reference_Number, Registration_id, Registration_Status
```

I would like to be able to pass in the `Reference_Number` as the parameter, from here the statement selects the `registration_id` from the relevant row in the table, then this is passed to the update statement to perform the update

Comment: Is Reference_Number unique per row? If so you can simply use it in the where clause - you don't need to first (select the registration_id from the relevant row)

Comment: Put `@Reference_Number` in parameter list, then `update dbo.Test1 set Registration_Status = @registration_status where Reference_Number = @Reference_Number` ... ?

Comment: @Milney it is unique, however i tried this and got errors saying the equals function does not work for txt variables

Comment: You should change the data type to varchar instead. Text is deprecated. But you could do WHERE CAST(registration_number as varchar(max)) = @parameter

Comment: @user3172765 Try my answer posted below, but do consider changing the data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you can probably do this;

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spUpdate1]    
 @registration_status int,
 @reference_number nvarchar(max)      
AS    
BEGIN    
    UPDATE t1
    SET    registration_status = @registration_status 
    FROM   dbo.Test1 t1
    WHERE  CAST(t1.reference_number as NVARCHAR(MAX)) = @reference_number     
END
```

Although I recommend changing the data type of Reference_Number to nvarchar(max) instead of text...

Comment: Or even better than varchar(max) is to find a reasonable size. Do you really need to allow more than 4,000 characters for a reference number? My guess is (n)varchar(10) or so would be totally sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you wanted ? based on `Reference_Number` to get the Registration_id ?

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spUpdate1]

 @registration_id nchar(8),
 @registration_status int,
 @Reference_Number nchar(8)   -- added this

AS

BEGIN

    update t2
    set    Registration_Status = @registration_status 
    from   dbo.Test1 t1
           inner join dbo.Test1 t2 on t1.Registration_id = t2.Registration_id 
    where  t1.Reference_Number  = @Reference_Number 

END
```

Comment: How could this be anonymously downvoted?  It looks like the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Wasn't me but noticed that the code will not run as the Registration_Status column will be ambiguous between the two tables so needs qualified with an alias - secondly the inner join is unnecessary and doesn't do anything, also registration_id is left in parameters list but not used in the query, and finally comments point out that Reference_number is text type column so cannot be compared with = so it isn't quite correct

Comment: @Milney . .  No.  `Registration_Status` is only referenced for assignment in the `set`, so it is unambiguously referring to `table2`.  The inner join is *specifically* what the OP needs to answer the question.  This is correct.

Comment: Why is the inner join needed, this is directly equivalent to just doing UPDATE Test Set registration_status = \@registration_status WHERE reference_number = \@reference_number as the join simply joins to the exact same rows....

Comment: Aside from that the text comparison will not work so as is the answer is incorrect